# getting value from a list contained within a dictionary value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

so I have a dictionary containing values that are a class containing a list of doubles, and I'm trying to get a specific number value from the list contained within the dictionary; for every value in the dictionary. What I mean is that for each item in the dictionary, I want the 8th item in its list value, for example. Here's the code I have:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ListClass> pair in MyDictionary)
{
    pair.Value.MyList[7];
}
```

my list class is definition looks like this:

```
public class ListClass
{
    public List<double> MyList = new List<double>();
}
```

This line trying to get the 8th value in the list has an error, and I'm not sure how to correct it. The error says "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement". I've also checked to make sure the dictionary has all the information it needs to do this, all its lists have over the 8 doubles needed. I'm sorry if this seems like a simple problem, I'm new to programming and am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `an error` and the error is...? Also show the class definition for `ListClass`. Why are the lists contained within that class to begin with?

Comment: More details are necessary, but I would check and see if ListClass has a getter of any kind that you would likely be better off using that.  Also, to get the 8th value in the list, you would use pair.Value.MyList[7];

Comment: If you don't have some custom indexer for MyList, then `[8]` will return 9th item, not 8th one. Indexing in C# starts from zero. Anyway, if you have error, always add its description to question

Comment: Likely that list doesn't have 9 items in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is because you aren't doing anything with the value. Just saying "get this value" and then not doing anything with it doesn't make sense to the compiler.

Assign it to a variable or use it in a method call and the error will go away.

For example:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ListClass> pair in MyDictionary)
{
    var eighthValue = pair.Value.MyList[7];
}
```

Just assigning it to a variable is still useless (you need to still use it later for this to make sense) but it will compile.

Comment: thank you, I can't believe I didn't try that, I was looking everywhere else trying to figure out what it could be. Thanks again